# Huge Heap Blocks number in postgres query planner

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to tune a complex SQL query(Can't post here due to organization policy). While going through query plan i found out that huge 'Heap scans' value spiking up query execution time and utilizes almost all the resources available in RDS. Would like to know how can i bring it down to acceptable value?

```
Aggregate  (cost=19967.440..19967.450 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=356827.833..356827.834 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=7783.550..19774.270 rows=765 width=80) (actual time=1396.970..356657.528 rows=1357 loops=1)
          Hash Cond: (alpha_quebec.juliet_victor = kilo_sierra.quebec_seven)
        ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=7773.230..19760.700 rows=765 width=104) (actual time=1396.946..356647.666 rows=1357 loops=1)
                Hash Cond: (alpha_two.quebec_seven = mike_lima.hotel)
              ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=6407.130..18391.610 rows=765 width=128) (actual time=555.112..355801.185 rows=1357 loops=1)
                      Hash Cond: (alpha_quebec.quebec_seven = six_kilo.hotel)
                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=5041.040..17022.640 rows=765 width=152) (actual time=90.547..355332.942 rows=1357 loops=1)
                          ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=3672.570..13310.410 rows=765 width=168) (actual time=90.527..1692.694 rows=1357 loops=1)
                                ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=3672.290..9707.350 rows=765 width=160) (actual time=89.430..648.944 rows=1357 loops=1)
                                        Hash Cond: (sierra(alpha_quebec.bravo) = three.quebec_seven)
                                      ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=3671.250..9607.780 rows=765 width=184) (actual time=88.918..643.314 rows=1357 loops=1)
                                              Hash Cond: (alpha_quebec.foxtrot_sierra = romeo_lima.quebec_seven)
                                            ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=2666.800..8596.630 rows=765 width=208) (actual time=64.133..616.054 rows=1357 loops=1)
                                                    Hash Cond: (alpha_quebec.quebec_seven = yankee_tango_six.hotel)
                                                  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=1561.140..7469.930 rows=765 width=208) (actual time=59.295..604.672 rows=1357 loops=1)
                                                          Hash Cond: (alpha_quebec.quebec_seven = zulu_four.hotel)
                                                        ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=454.600..6360.510 rows=765 width=208) (actual time=29.880..571.878 rows=1357 loops=1)
                                                                Hash Cond: (sierra(alpha_quebec.foxtrot_yankee) = delta_whiskey.quebec_seven)
                                                              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on zulu_charlie alpha_quebec  (cost=191.900..5995.490 rows=765 width=232) (actual time=19.030..527.055 rows=1357 loops=1)
                                                                      Recheck Cond: ((quebec_seven >= 'seven'::bytea) AND (quebec_seven <= 'mike_four'::bytea))
                                                                      Filter: (NOT whiskey_yankee)
                                                                      Heap Blocks: exact=804
                                                                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on six_india  (cost=0.000..191.710 rows=1529 width=0) (actual time=17.534..17.534 rows=1357 loops=1)
                                                                            Index Cond: ((quebec_seven >= 'seven'::bytea) AND (quebec_seven <= 'mike_four'::bytea))
                                                              ->  Hash  (cost=249.350..249.350 rows=1068 width=40) (actual time=6.931..6.931 rows=2153 loops=1)
                                                                      Buckets: 4096 (originally 2048)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 152kB
                                                                    ->  Seq Scan on two_oscar delta_whiskey  (cost=0.000..249.350 rows=1068 width=40) (actual time=0.844..5.628 rows=2153 loops=1)
                                                                            Filter: (NOT whiskey_yankee)
                                                        ->  Hash  (cost=1104.370..1104.370 rows=173 width=32) (actual time=29.408..29.409 rows=281 loops=1)
                                                                Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 22kB
                                                              ->  Subquery Scan on zulu_four  (cost=1100.050..1104.370 rows=173 width=32) (actual time=28.947..29.296 rows=281 loops=1)
                                                                    ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=1100.050..1102.640 rows=173 width=96) (actual time=28.945..29.203 rows=281 loops=1)
                                                                            Group Key: juliet_xray.hotel
                                                                          ->  Sort  (cost=1100.050..1100.480 rows=173 width=32) (actual time=28.937..28.992 rows=281 loops=1)
                                                                                  Sort Key: juliet_xray.hotel
                                                                                  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 46kB
                                                                                ->  Hash Join  (cost=7.430..1093.620 rows=173 width=32) (actual time=9.474..28.581 rows=281 loops=1)
                                                                                        Hash Cond: (juliet_xray.romeo_zulu = romeo_three.quebec_seven)
                                                                                      ->  Seq Scan on charlie juliet_xray  (cost=0.000..1081.500 rows=788 width=64) (actual time=6.817..25.627 rows=281 loops=1)
                                                                                              Filter: ((NOT whiskey_yankee) AND zulu_uniform)
                                                                                              Rows Removed by Filter: 11474
                                                                                      ->  Hash  (cost=6.880..6.880 rows=44 width=32) (actual time=2.629..2.629 rows=88 loops=1)
                                                                                              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 13kB
                                                                                            ->  Seq Scan on lima romeo_three  (cost=0.000..6.880 rows=44 width=32) (actual time=0.840..2.569 rows=88 loops=1)
                                                                                                    Filter: (NOT whiskey_yankee)
                                                  ->  Hash  (cost=1103.160..1103.160 rows=200 width=32) (actual time=4.822..4.822 rows=1305 loops=1)
                                                          Buckets: 2048 (originally 1024)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 79kB
                                                        ->  Subquery Scan on yankee_tango_six  (cost=1099.160..1103.160 rows=200 width=32) (actual time=3.490..4.413 rows=1306 loops=1)
                                                              ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1099.160..1101.160 rows=200 width=96) (actual time=3.489..3.893 rows=1306 loops=1)
                                                                      Group Key: india1.hotel
                                                                    ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=7.430..1098.300 rows=346 width=32) (actual time=0.086..2.867 rows=1391 loops=1)
                                                                            Hash Cond: (india1.romeo_zulu = six_lima1.quebec_seven)
                                                                          ->  Seq Scan on charlie quebec_oscar_zulu_seven  (cost=0.000..1081.500 rows=1575 width=64) (actual time=0.003..2.086 rows=1306 loops=1)
                                                                                  Filter: (NOT whiskey_yankee)
                                                                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 10449
                                                                          ->  Hash  (cost=6.880..6.880 rows=44 width=32) (actual time=0.067..0.067 rows=88 loops=1)
                                                                                  Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 13kB
                                                                                ->  Seq Scan on lima victor_echo  (cost=0.000..6.880 rows=44 width=32) (actual time=0.005..0.039 rows=88 loops=1)
                                                                                        Filter: (NOT whiskey_yankee)
                                            ->  Hash  (cost=847.740..847.740 rows=12537 width=40) (actual time=24.720..24.720 rows=23917 loops=1)
                                                    Buckets: 32768 (originally 16384)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 1588kB
                                                  ->  Seq Scan on delta_juliet romeo_lima  (cost=0.000..847.740 rows=12537 width=40) (actual time=1.960..15.639 rows=23917 loops=1)
                                                          Filter: (NOT whiskey_yankee)
                                      ->  Hash  (cost=1.020..1.020 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=0.481..0.481 rows=1 loops=1)
                                              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                                            ->  Seq Scan on whiskey_november three  (cost=0.000..1.020 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=0.478..0.479 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                    Filter: ((NOT whiskey_yankee) AND ((two_charlie)::text = 'victor_lima'::text))
                                                    Rows Removed by Filter: 1
                                ->  Index Scan using golf_sierra on quebec_oscar_zulu_papa alpha_two  (cost=0.290..4.700 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=0.761..0.765 rows=1 loops=1357)
                                        Index Cond: (quebec_seven = alpha_quebec.tango_yankee)
                                        Filter: (NOT whiskey_yankee)
                          ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=1368.460..1371.520 rows=1 width=48) (actual time=218.485..260.014 rows=0 loops=1357)
                                  Hash Cond: (yankee_zulu.hotel = victor_hotel.quebec_seven)
                                ->  Unique  (cost=1361.850..1363.010 rows=137 width=7905) (actual time=450.463..644.573 rows=64383 loops=491)
                                      ->  Sort  (cost=1361.850..1362.430 rows=232 width=7905) (actual time=450.461..524.690 rows=64383 loops=491)
                                              Sort Key: yankee_zulu.hotel
                                            ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on yankee_zulu  (cost=39.950..1352.740 rows=232 width=7905) (actual time=25.050..203.538 rows=64383 loops=491)
                                                    Recheck Cond: ((kilo_two)::text = 'mike_papa'::text)
                                                    Filter: (NOT whiskey_yankee)
                                                    Heap Blocks: exact=1656634
                                                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on four  (cost=0.000..39.890 rows=463 width=0) (actual time=23.773..23.773 rows=64383 loops=491)
                                                          Index Cond: ((kilo_two)::text = 'mike_papa'::text)
                                ->  Hash  (cost=6.600..6.600 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=1.350..1.350 rows=0 loops=1357)
                                        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 8kB
                                      ->  Index Scan using november on xray victor_hotel  (cost=0.660..6.600 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=1.340..1.341 rows=0 loops=1357)
                                              Index Cond: (sierra(alpha_quebec.kilo_kilo) = quebec_seven)
                                              Filter: (NOT whiskey_yankee)
                                              Rows Removed by Filter: 0
                    ->  Hash  (cost=1364.380..1364.380 rows=137 width=40) (actual time=464.550..464.551 rows=31262 loops=1)
                            Buckets: 32768 (originally 1024)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 1997kB
                          ->  Subquery Scan on six_kilo  (cost=1361.850..1364.380 rows=137 width=40) (actual time=398.701..450.745 rows=31262 loops=1)
                                ->  Unique  (cost=1361.850..1363.010 rows=137 width=7905) (actual time=398.700..432.354 rows=31262 loops=1)
                                      ->  Sort  (cost=1361.850..1362.430 rows=232 width=7905) (actual time=398.695..412.188 rows=31347 loops=1)
                                              Sort Key: five1.hotel
                                              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 3217kB
                                            ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on yankee_zulu victor_zulu  (cost=39.950..1352.740 rows=232 width=7905) (actual time=170.383..371.245 rows=31347 loops=1)
                                                    Recheck Cond: ((kilo_two)::text = 'kilo_six'::text)
                                                    Filter: (NOT whiskey_yankee)
                                                    Heap Blocks: exact=1272
                                                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on four  (cost=0.000..39.890 rows=463 width=0) (actual time=169.794..169.794 rows=31347 loops=1)
                                                          Index Cond: ((kilo_two)::text = 'kilo_six'::text)
              ->  Hash  (cost=1364.380..1364.380 rows=137 width=40) (actual time=841.806..841.806 rows=17638 loops=1)
                      Buckets: 32768 (originally 1024)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 1238kB
                    ->  Subquery Scan on mike_lima  (cost=1361.850..1364.380 rows=137 width=40) (actual time=786.540..830.724 rows=17638 loops=1)
                          ->  Unique  (cost=1361.850..1363.010 rows=137 width=7905) (actual time=786.538..815.928 rows=17638 loops=1)
                                ->  Sort  (cost=1361.850..1362.430 rows=232 width=7905) (actual time=786.536..797.997 rows=22005 loops=1)
                                        Sort Key: five2.hotel
                                        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 2488kB
                                      ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on yankee_zulu golf_november  (cost=39.950..1352.740 rows=232 width=7905) (actual time=75.120..759.345 rows=22005 loops=1)
                                              Recheck Cond: ((kilo_two)::text = 'yankee_tango_papa'::text)
                                              Filter: (NOT whiskey_yankee)
                                              Heap Blocks: exact=1810
                                            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on four  (cost=0.000..39.890 rows=463 width=0) (actual time=74.894..74.894 rows=22005 loops=1)
                                                    Index Cond: ((kilo_two)::text = 'yankee_tango_papa'::text)
        ->  Hash  (cost=10.200..10.200 rows=10 width=40) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=0 loops=1)
                Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 8kB
              ->  Seq Scan on tango_delta kilo_sierra  (cost=0.000..10.200 rows=10 width=40) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=0 loops=1)
                      Filter: (NOT whiskey_yankee)
```

Some of the things i have tried so far:

1. **Vaccum full analyze**
2. **SET default_statistics_target = 1000;**
3. **SELECT * FROM pg_stat_all_tables order by n_tup_del;**

Other details:

1. The same query for the same dataset in other machine works well and comes up with entirely different plan.
2. Same query for similar sized dataset but different database does work well and chooses different query plan.

EDIT:

Below is the query plan for table yankee_zulu:

```
Unique  (cost=1631.390..1666.610 rows=313 width=7905) (actual time=1398.556..1493.042 rows=64383 loops=1)
    Buffers: shared hit=20 read=3248, temp read=1587 written=1587
  ->  Sort  (cost=1631.390..1632.180 rows=313 width=7905) (actual time=1398.554..1431.475 rows=64383 loops=1)
          Sort Key: quebec_seven, "india", six_india, whiskey_yankee, two_quebec, romeo_oscar, quebec_five, tango_xray, whiskey_papa, alpha_mike, tango_bravo, oscar, alpha_india, foxtrot, romeo_zulu, kilo_lima, charlie, november_lima, november_lima2, november_lima3, hotel_oscar, victor, two_oscar, two_charlie, six_whiskey, three_foxtrot, two_bravo, xray, golf, echo, romeo_juliet, kilo_kilo, yankee_five, november_quebec, bravo_kilo, hotel_five, papa, five, lima_sierra, six_victor, bravo_india, alpha_tango, lima_victor, three_whiskey
          Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 12664kB
          Buffers: shared hit=20 read=3248, temp read=1587 written=1587
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on yankee_zulu  (cost=17.190..1618.420 rows=313 width=7905) (actual time=15.070..1185.803 rows=64383 loops=1)
                Recheck Cond: ((kilo_two)::text = 'mike'::text)
                Filter: (NOT whiskey_yankee)
                Heap Blocks: exact=2999
                Buffers: shared read=3248
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on four  (cost=0.000..17.110 rows=626 width=0) (actual time=12.311..12.311 rows=64383 loops=1)
                      Index Cond: ((kilo_two)::text = 'mike'::text)
                      Buffers: shared read=249
```

Only observation is massive miscalculation by the query planner which is not getting corrected even after vaccum and increasing statistics for this table.

Comment: @jjanes I have added edit

Comment: On the other machine which is faster, can you identify and post the part of the explain plan which corresponds to the `select distinct * from yankee_zulu where kilo_two='mike_papa' and not whiskey_yankee`?  Or, if you can get the two plan to be anonymous sized the same way, include the full plan from the faster machine?

Comment: After changing default_statistics_target, did you re-do the "VACUUM ANALYZE" (or just ANALYZE) of the table?  The change does not take effect until an ANALYZE is done.

Comment: so after running ANALYZE it seem to work very well. VACUUM ANALYZE   doesn't run ANALYZE?

Comment: It does.  But your workflow showed you running VACUUM FULL ANALYZE **before** changing  default_statistics_target, not after.